# How to use PHP in IPS Community suite

Tags: php

I am trying to add < php > script to my design template, those tags just outputs the text. Any script isn't working. Is there any solution to write php script in template?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson IPS is CMS. And the web extension is index.php. But the script editor doesn't allow to output PHP, or I don't know the way how to do it.

Comment: Ok. So this is basically a support question about a specific software? Then I would recommend asking their support/forum. SO is for when you have programming issues with your code, not a general software support/helpdesk.